# Browser cookies lost when switching desktop environment

Tags: linux, fedora, kde, plasma, enlightenment

Each time I switch between Enlightenment and KDE Plasma, Chromium seems to loose all cookies and I need to re-login to any web service I use (really annoying). Is this a known problem? Can I do anything to prevent this?

Comment: Similar report: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=282066 (except that my cookies are still lost even if I switch back)

Comment: Another related one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374986/google-chrome-looses-all-cookies-when-logging-in-a-different-desktop-environment